Why $\int_{\mathbb R}e^{i\omega t}dt=2\pi \delta (\omega )$?
In a text book on signal, it's written $\int_{\mathbb R}e^{i\omega t}dt=2\pi \delta (\omega ).$
Could someone help me to understand why? It was my understanding that $\int_{\mathbb R}e^{i\omega t}dt$ is not defined which seemingly conflicts with the textbook result.

You may interprete this expression as the continuous analog of the orthogonality relation of the Fourier basis.

This is to be interpreted as a Schwartz distribution. It means:
for all continuous $\phi : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ with compact support,
$$
\int_{\mathbb R}\int_\mathbb R \phi(\omega) e^{i\omega t}\;d\omega\;dt
=2\pi \phi(0)
$$

The formula is explained in distribution theory from the following facts:

The Fourier transform of $\delta$ is the constant function $1$.
$\mathcal{F}\{\mathcal{F}\{f(t)\}\}=2\pi f(-t).$

These give
$$
\mathcal{F}\{1\}
= \mathcal{F}\{\mathcal{F}\{\delta(t)\}\}
= 2\pi\delta(-t)
= 2\pi\delta(t).
$$
Writing $\mathcal{F}\{1\}$ formally as an integral we thus get
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i\omega t} \, dt = 2\pi\delta(\omega).
$$

I think that here, a math forum, computations with divergent integrals should include more explanation.

Another way to state this: if the Fourier transform of $\delta$ is the constant function $1$, then the inverse FT of $1$ is $\delta$.

Physicists and engineers are well familiar with the formula as presented here. They interpret it as follows: if one takes a large number of sinusoidal signals with amplitudes equal to $1$ and times $t$ from a broad spectrum, the sum of the signals tends to zero for all frequencies due to destructive interference; except for a narrow frequency region around $\omega = 0$, where a spike arises due to constructive interference.
This is a rather loose interpretation. A physicist or engineer will support this reasoning by multiplying the integrand on the LHS by a suitable window function $W(t, \tau)$. Inside the window one has $W=1$ and outside $W$ tends to zero. $\tau$ represents the width of the window. The integral is now well-defined and converges.
The most-often used example of such a window is the Gaussian $W(t, \tau) = \exp(-t^2/(2\tau^2))$. If we substitute this in the LHS, the integral is easily evaluated and we obtain the RHS, where the delta function is represented by a Gaussian. Other window functions lead to different representations of the Dirac delta function.
From this calculation we see that the formula as presented is a kind of short-hand notation. Actually it is more appropriate to write the formula with a window function. In the limit of an infinitely broad window the original formula is obtained.

Another way to look at the role of the window function is that, upon carrying out the integral with the window function present, what is obtained is not the Dirac delta function but a nascent delta function. So the window approach gives a general recipe for generating such nascent delta functions.
